# Strange error during running GWT 2.7 in DevMode

Tags: java, gwt

What is wrong?

I founded some discussion about it but without solution
https://plus.googleapis.com/communities/116543000751323604177/stream/1cf77106-8055-472e-abb2-ac58a512b663

```
09:43:36.128 [ERROR] [MyApplication] Exception initializing module
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker$CompileDependencyVisitor.<init>(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:227)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:209)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:42)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:37)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:366)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:580)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:101)
```

Comment: Did you mean to link to https://plus.google.com/104837083947799018577/posts/ayTkW6VkbgC ? From that discussion: check your classpath, you might have an incompatible version of ASM in there.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with ASM. GWT 2.7 required ASM 5.x

Comment: @ThomasBroyer you should provide the solution as an answer now that it's certain that you were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you have an incompatible version of ASM in the classpath. GWT requires ASM 5+

Comment: This was fixed for me by updating Google App Engine in my project to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath may have some misconfiguration. In my case, I had a 2.8 project that worked just fine, but newer projects had that stackt race for a some reason. I don't know what caused this, but the solution in my case was to change this part of the .classpath:

```
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER/App Engine"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>
```

to:

```
   <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER"/>
   <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER/GWT"/>
```