# How to remove entry from the GWT SDK execution classpath

Tags: maven, gwt, migration, classpath

I am trying to upgrade my application from version 2.6.1 to 2.7 and I am getting follwoing exception executing goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on my project:

```
[INFO] Compiling module cern.edms.ui.Application
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker$CompileDependencyVisitor.<init>(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:59)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:227)
```

I found information that it could be because of the wrong version of the ASM in my classpath ([Strange error during running GWT 2.7 in DevMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425189/strange-error-during-running-gwt-2-7-in-devmode)), therefore I've check it. And indeed in my classpath there is two version of ASM:4.2 and 5.0.3. It is because one of the dependency has dependency on cglib which has dependency on ASM 4.2. GWT has dependency on ASM 5.0.3.

Here is my full classpath:

```
[DEBUG] GWT SDK execution classpath :
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-ui\target\edms-ui-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-ui\src\main\java
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-ui\target\generated-sources\gwt
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-ui\target\generated-sources\gwt\**
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-procedures\target\edms-procedures-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.3.0\ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-core-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.5.4\javax.mail-1.5.4.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-shared\target\edms-shared.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\dev\Workspace\EDMS-APP\20151015_java7_gwt27\trunk\edms-search\target\edms-search.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\3.1\cglib-3.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\4.2\asm-4.2.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-ws-core\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ws\spring-xml\2.1.4.RELEASE\spring-xml-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-oxm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.2.4.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\wsdl4j\wsdl4j\1.6.1\wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.1\httpclient-4.3.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3\httpcore-4.3.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\weblogic\wls-api\12.1.1\wls-api-12.1.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\ch\cern\sso\wlsAttributeNameMapper\1.9\wlsAttributeNameMapper-1.9.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.7.0\gwt-user-2.7.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\web\bindery\requestfactory-server\2.7.0\requestfactory-server-2.7.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\extjs\gxt\2.3.1a-gwt22\gxt-2.3.1a-gwt22.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\sencha\gxt\gxt\3.1.4\gxt-3.1.4.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\mvp4g\mvp4g\1.4.0\mvp4g-1.4.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\inject\gin\1.5.0\gin-1.5.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0-rc2\guice-3.0-rc2.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-assistedinject\3.0-rc2\guice-assistedinject-3.0-rc2.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.8.2\aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.2\aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\persistence-api\1.0\persistence-api-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.0.9.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.1.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.1.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final-sources.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.1\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0.1\guava-14.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwtmockito\gwtmockito\1.1.5\gwtmockito-1.1.5.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.7.0\gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\5.0.3\asm-util-5.0.3.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\5.0.3\asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\5.0.3\asm-commons-5.0.3.jar
[DEBUG]    C:\Users\kpater\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.17.1-GA\javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar
```

How can I exclude ASM in version 4.2 from the classpath?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd just split your project into separate modules for client and server code so you avoid classpath conflicts like this one. You can draw inspiration from those archetypes: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

However, given that ASM 4+ guarantees backward compatibility, you could also just use ASM 5 instead of ASM 4:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-parent</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to build the project by excluding the ASM in cglib dependency. Here is my code:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>cglib</groupId>
  <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It builds, but does it run? Doing that, you're excluding ASM from your runtime classpath too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming gwt-maven-plugin documentation, you can set the runClasspathExclude property to exclude jars from the classPath when running dev mode (and only in DEV mode) :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <runClasspathExcludes>
                    <runClasspathExclude>jetty-webapp-9.2.4.v20141103.jar</runClasspathExclude>
                    <runClasspathExclude>jetty-xml-9.2.4.v20141103.jar</runClasspathExclude>
                    <runClasspathExclude>jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar</runClasspathExclude>
                    <runClasspathExclude>jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar</runClasspathExclude>
                    <runClasspathExclude>jetty-security-9.2.4.v20141103.jar</runClasspathExclude>
                </runClasspathExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Note that this configuration is used by the "run" goal only : mvn gwt:run